# gradle build only include dependents modules, exclude 3rd jars

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a three modules project. Module C dependents on module B, and module B dependents on module A.

Now i want to publish module C, and i hope module C includes module A and B's classes.

I tried this, but it includes 3rd part jars:

```
jar {
    from {
    //    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        configurations.compile.collect { it }
    }
}
```

Looking forward to your reply, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it:

```
configurations.compile.filter {XXXX}.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
```